# Python format Decimal near zero

Tags: python, numbers, decimal

I'm trying to parse a near 0 number using the decimal.Decimal python module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal("0.00000161")
Decimal('0.00000161')
>>> Decimal("0.00000061")
Decimal('6.1E-7')
>>>
```

What would be the best way to print "0.00000061" instead of "6.1E-7"?

Comment: What's the problem with scientific notation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [157]: from decimal import Decimal

In [158]: x = Decimal("0.00000061")

In [159]: format(x, 'f')
Out[159]: '0.00000061'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal('0.00000061')
print '{0:f}'.format(x)
```